# .NET MAUI always gives the original orientation even after changing the orientation on the Android emulator

Tags: android-emulator, maui, screen-orientation

This is kind of silly, but

```cs
private void OnButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Orientaion", DeviceDisplay.Current.MainDisplayInfo.Orientation.ToString(), "OK");
}
```

always gives "portrait" (with a phone emulator) or "landscape" (with a tablet emulator) even after I switch the orientation. It just gives the default orientation even after the emulator successfully changes it.

What am I missing?

Comment: It's unclear what the problem is. Does the content of the emulator change orientation when your app is not running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can recheck if you have enabled option `Auto-rotate` on your Android device.

Swipe down on your phone's screen, and then you will find the `Auto-rotate` option.

[image]